# Get Option Value Without Index?

Tags: angular

I need to get the selected dropdown value when changed
But when I set the value with ngValue, it is prepending an index
(makes no sense why)

How can I get just the value?

Actual values in source
Index added to value!?
0: `Campus A`
1: `Campus B`
2: `Campus C`

```
    <form [formGroup]="preferredCampus">
      <select id="campus" formControlName="campus" #t (change)="campusChanged(t.value)">
        <option *ngFor="let i of campusInfo.campuses" [ngValue]="i.Name">{{ i.Name }}</option>
      </select>
    </form>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `[value]` rather than `[ngValue]`?

Comment: Oh, thanks R.  
That works.  
For some reason, I though ngValue was only the "proper" way to set the value.  
New user ignorance.

Comment: @R.Richards can create an answer based on his comment and you mark it as resolve! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `[value]` rather than `[ngValue]` in this situation.

Using `[value]` works well with simple values, like strings.

`[ngValue]` is best used when you want to use an object as a value.

More details: https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#how-to-use

Answer (score 0):

You should use just `value` instead of `ngValue`.